# In Glide 3.x, Is it possible to use different cache directories for different images?

Tags: android, image, caching, android-glide

My overall object is to `delete` certain type of images (which are temporary) after a certain period like after one month, from disk cache of the my app.

I'm using Glide, so I know that using Glide, I can clear entire `disk Cache` but my goal is to clear only a certain type of `images` from `disk cache`. Like for example, live `banner` images from my app (which keeps changing after certain period). Problem is, they keeps adding space even though one gets `inactive`. So ideally I should delete all old `banner` images from cache.

What I'm thinking is have a separate `Glide Module` just for these banner images and setup a different `internal cache` directory for these images, and after a month, ask `Glide` to delete/clear this directory.

Another thing is to use `Glide's signature` concept which invalidates the images.

For both of above ideas, my problem and question is that I want to use only for certain type of images but more I read about them, it feels like once I use them, they apply to all images being download using `Glide`

Even if I use multiple Glide module, they all gets used for all the images (that's why there is a concept of conflict management for glide modules)

I might be wrong, and there might be indeed a way to get a solution to my problem. All I need is your help if you know a way :)

I'm aware that if nothing works out for my solution, then to keep my app's size impact low, I'll have to decreased overall `internal disk cache` size which is `250MB` by default.

Thanks.